# magento export products with custom field

Tags: magento, dataflow

I'm using dataflow - profiles to export all products.

But I need more columns from the default column mapper. I need the following columns

1. Entity ID
2. Category Name (default available is Category ID)
3. Additional images (default is main image only)

Furthermore, i want to prepend image URL and product URL with store URL (eg. current product URL exported is product-01.html, instead of that, I want it in http://www.example.com/product-01.html)

Appreciated with everyone helps

Comment: I have worked it out and answered it here, as that is where magento questions belong:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32915/dataflow-export-product-entity-id/32916#32916

Answer (score 0):

Search for any extensions if available.   Not supported in default Magento.
Also, for images you can use three columns "image", "small_image" and "thumbnail"
Repeat these on to next record if images exceed three.